# How to format a specific time/hour coming from an excel file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, time

I am receiving this from an excel file:

[image]

And on React I am trying to do this:

```js
<Card.Footer>{r.start} - {r.end}</Card.Footer>
```

And that renders:

```js
0.3333333333333333 - 0.5
```

So I want to know why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the expected result? Date and time in Excel is stored as number of days, so 0.5 is 12 hours

Comment: have you tried it with momentjs?

Comment: @Slai i needed to be the same as it looks in the excel file.

Comment: @UmairRiaz I can not use moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel time number can be multiplied by 86400000 (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) to convert it to `Date`, and [`.toLocaleString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) method can be used to get the desired format :

```js
const formatTime = days => new Date(days * 864e5).toLocaleString('en-US', 
                                { timeStyle: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC' });

console.log( `${formatTime(0.3333333333333333)} - ${formatTime(0.5)}` );
```